# Spring 4 mail configuration via java config

Tags: spring, email, spring-java-config

Is there some example of how MailSender can be configured via java config? 
All examples that I've seen uses xml to create needed beans:

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
   <property name="host" value="mail.mycompany.com"/>
</bean>

<!-- this is a template message that we can pre-load with default state -->
 <bean id="templateMessage" class="org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage">
 <property name="from" value="customerservice@mycompany.com"/>
 <property name="subject" value="Your order"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The code you posted (along with some small improvements to make it more configurable) would be transformed into the following Java config:

```
@Configuration 
public class MailConfig {

    @Value("${email.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${email.from}")
    private String from;

    @Value("${email.subject}")
    private String subject;

    @Bean
    public JavaMailSender javaMailService() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        javaMailSender.setHost(host);
        return javaMailSender;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleMailMessage simpleMailMessage() {
       SimpleMailMessage simpleMailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();
       simpleMailMessage.setFrom(from);
       simpleMailMessage.setSubject(subject);
       return simpleMailMessage;
    }
}
```

You should also be aware of the fact that Spring Boot (which you have not mentioned whether or not you are using) can auto-configure an `JavaMailSender` for you. Check out [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-email) part of the documentation

Comment: Hi, I know it old post, but I use your code to in my project, I only added parameter into function like that simpleMailMessage(String body) {...} . Can you tell me how can I use that beans please?

Comment: @DenisStephanov [This](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mail) part of the documentation should clear up the usage for you

Comment: This don't help me, because it demonstration of sending emails but my problem is how to use it as beans. Should I autowired that? If yes how to do that with parameter in my function which creates SimpleMailMessage ?:/

Comment: In the documentation above it's fairly clear how to set the body in the `placeOrder` method. As for autowiring, all you need to do is autowire the `SimpleMailMessage` into whatever class you will sending the email from

Answer (score 0):

```
@Configuration 
public class AppConfig {

    @Value("${mail.host}")
    private String host;


    @Bean
    public JavaMailSender emailService() {
        JavaMailSender javaMailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        javaMailSender.setHost(host);
        return javaMailSender;
    }



@Component
public class EmailServiceImpl implements EmailService {

    @Autowired
    public JavaMailSender emailSender;

    public void sendSimpleMessage( String to, String subject, String text) {
        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage(); 
        message.setTo(to); 
        message.setSubject(subject); 
        message.setText(text);
        emailSender.send(message);
    }
}
```