# Spring: confusion over the right learning path

Tags: spring, spring-boot

The past few days I've been teaching myself Spring Boot and created a REST web service server and client, then added basic authentication and deployed as a standalone and a war package. I did this through incorporating `spring-boot-starter-web`, `spring-boot-starter-test`, `spring-boot-starter`, `spring-boot-starter-security`, `spring-boot-starter-tomcat`, `spring-web`, `jackson-databind` in my gradle project and copying hten modifying via various websites.

After getting confused by the multitude of websites doing things in completely different ways (completely different annotations, some use of configuration files) it worked and I then modified it using an interceptor/message converter, raw headers and then through a rest template builder.

However, I feel like I really have no idea how or why it worked, even though I wrote a fair bit of code to get it all working, including Basic authentication, in 4 different ways. It just magically worked, and I don't like it: for example, if I wanted to add more stuff that wasn't 'boot' based, how would I do it, or what are all the annotations doing and why are they required, e.g. `@SpringBootApplication`, `@Configuration`, or why are some classes `@Bean` and others not).

To cut a long story short, spring is a massive framework (the website listing the packages takes over a page by itself), should I really be learning spring core/framework before anything else, then maybe spring MVC or spring web services before learning boot?

I can find many resources on teaching me the various packages, but none that tells me why they work or where to really start and specifically nothing will tell me how the packages interlink. It's quite overwhelming.

I expect this will get closed down as not constructive, but it seemed to be the best place to get an answer on Spring.

Comment: Your question is quite valid. This jungle of Configs and Methods is making me feel the same. Every book teaches something different, every version has it's different methods, someone aware of all (if not at least from the Spring team) should explain here.

Comment: I wouldn't go with Baeldung or the plethora of Udemy courses out there since I believe the instructors lack experience and you end up not getting the clarity. That being said Tim Buchalka upgraded his course on Udemy and he shows you many of the different ways you may encounter spring apps being written. THAT was a cheap way to have a professional launch me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## A very short history of Spring

Lets start with a little history lesson... The year is 2002 and most Java developers have been laboring in the J2EE space and a lot of them were not happy. One of them was Rod Johnson who wrote a book called [Expert One-on-One J2EE Design and Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764543857) and it was how one could develop enterprise application without EJBs and in a better fashion. The code for this book became the foundation of the Spring Framework.

## Spring Configuration

Lets take a look at a simple Java class.

```
@Component("hello")
public class HelloWorld {

    private String name = "World!";

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name=name;
    }

    public void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello, " + name);
    }
}
```

### Spring Configuration - Property Files

In the beginning the only configuration option was to use a properties file. Lets name this file `application-context.properties`. To create an instance of the java class above and set a name, the following content in the `application-context.properties` was needed.

```
hello.(class)=biz.deinum.samples.configurations.HelloWorld
hello.name=Marten!
```

The `(class)` was a special property (there are more like `(scope)` and `(abstract)` see the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/PropertiesBeanDefinitionReader.html) for more options. This would indicate which class was needed to be loaded. To use the properties file one would have to create a [`PropertiesBeanDefinitionReader`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/PropertiesBeanDefinitionReader.html) pass that a `BeanFactory`. (Which in turn can be passed to an `ApplicationContext` if you need fancy features like AOP)

```
DefaultListableBeanFactory beanFactory = new DefaultListableBeanFactory();
PropertiesBeanDefinitionReader reader = new PropertiesBeanDefinitionReader(beanFactory);
reader.loadBeanDefinitions("classpath:application-context.properties");

HelloWorld helloWorld = beanFactory.getBean("hello", HelloWorld.class);
helloWorld.sayHello();
```

However that property based configuration was a bit limiting and XML was concurring the world. Hence the first steps into XML configuration where born.

### Spring Configuration - XML Files (part 1)

To represent the same configuration with XML the following would be needed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="hello" class="biz.deinum.samples.configurations.HelloWorld">
        <property name="name" value="Marten!" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

When loaded this would create an instance of `HelloWorld` with the same settings as the property file. Loading it would require an `XmlBeanDefinitionReader`.

```
DefaultListableBeanFactory beanFactory = new DefaultListableBeanFactory();
XmlBeanDefinitionReader reader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(beanFactory);
reader.loadBeanDefinitions("classpath:/applicationContext-basic.xml");

HelloWorld helloWorld = beanFactory.getBean("hello", HelloWorld.class);
helloWorld.sayHello();
```

### Spring Configuration - XML Files (part 2)

XML is quite verbose but readable. But configuring things like AOP (Transactions for instance),MVC etc. are quite labor some. (Or things like security see [this](http://netzooid.com/blog/2007/12/03/every-time-you-use-acegi/) for the predecessor of Spring Security without a namespace). So the new and improved XML had the notion of namespaces allowing things like `<tx:annotation-driven />` `<aop:config />` etc.

### Spring Configuration - Annotation Driven

The next step was the introduction of Java5, which allowed annotations. As the whole Java community asked for annotation based configuration this was added. Hence the introduction of `@Component`, `@Autowired` and the likes.

Adding `@Component` to the `HelloWorld` class and use the namespace to enable component scanning reduces the amount of XML one has to write.

Assuming `@Component("hello")` is on the `HelloWorld` class the following XML is needed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="biz.deinum.samples.configurations" />

</beans>
```

To load this configuration the just change the location of the file to load.

### Spring Configuration - Java Config

Then all of a sudden the love for XML was over and people wanted to use a language they know and that language is Java. Hence the birth of Java Based configuration.

```
@Configuration
public class HelloWorldConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public HelloWorld hello() {
        HelloWorld helloWorld = new HelloWorld();
        helloWorld.setName("Marten!");
        return helloWorld;
    }
}
```

The `@Bean` annotation is an indication that this method produces a bean and is processed using ASM before being actually loaded by Spring. However Java Config processing is quite complex and works only with an `ApplicationContext`. You can either add the `@Configuration` class to an xml file and load that to have it processed or use a specialized `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` to load (or detect) it.

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(HelloWorldConfiguration.class);
context.getBean("hello", HelloWorld.class).sayHello();
```

In XML we have namespaces for making configuration easier. In Java Config land we have the various `@Enable*` annotations like `@EnableTransactionManagement` which is the same as `<tx:annotation-driven />` in XML.

### Thoughts / Suggestions

Which configuration option to use, if you are new I suggest start with Java based configuration, although XML is probably a bit easier to understand (IMHO). All configuration options still work today, you can even mix and match them if need arises.

For Spring it doesn't matter, what matters for Spring are the `BeanDefinition`s which source is used to construct them (properties, xml or java configuration) doesn't matter.

## Spring Boot

Thus far the only thing covered is Spring itself. No other project has been touched (although have been mentioned). But as you can imagine time goes on and as configurations and application complexity grew we wanted more [convention over configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration). One of the reasons Spring Boot has seen the light.

Marking a class with `@SpringBootApplication` makes that class a `@Configuration`, will enable component-scanning (starting from the same package the annotated class is in) and will enable auto configuration.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class HelloApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(HelloApplication.class, args);

        BeanFactoryHelper.sayHello(context);
        BeanFactoryHelper.statistics(context);
    }

    @Bean
    public HelloWorld hello() {

        HelloWorld hello = new HelloWorld();
        hello.setName("Marten!");
        return hello;
    }
}
```

This class will launch the application, say hello, print some info on the context and end. Without you creating an application context or factory yourself.

Why the `@Bean` method well the `HelloWorld` class is in a package not covered by the default component scanning of Spring Boot and hence we need to declare the bean. We can do this in the `HelloApplication` class because that is also an `@Configuration` (due to that being a meta annotation on `@SpringBootApplication`).

Now if you replace `@SpringBootApplication` with `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClasses = HelloWorld.class)` you could remove the `@Bean` annotation as the `HelloWorld` would now be detected by component scanning (enabled by the `@ComponentScan` meta annotation on `@SpringBootApplication`).

The code for this answer can be found [here](https://github.com/mdeinum/samples).

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for the indepth information. My thoughts on my progress...

I read V4 but it only seems to want to show XML samples. E.g. Mail is a good example, but for other forms while simpler you need to know the specific propery names which are not documented.

So I read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24097131/spring-4-mail-configuration-via-java-config

Which then says Boot negates this config/complexity: 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-email

but nothing concrete is detailed then points you back at the main library...

Comment: Every property in XML is a property in Java. XML uses Java Beans spec under the hood (so `property name="host"` translates to `setHost` this is according to the spec). And a good IDE will help you (like IntelliJ or STS and probably others as well).

Comment: Thanks. No need to answer further, this help has been great. I'm already using Eclipse so now I know, it'll be ok. I cannot use STS as it doesn't work for me (gradle fails in STS), but that's another question :)

Answer (score 3):

Spring framework it's about dependency injection and it's used for REST web services, but that doesn't mean you can't have Spring in any basic application.

> To cut a long story short, spring is a massive framework (the website listing the packages takes over a page by itself), should I really be learning spring core/framework before anything else, then maybe spring MVC or spring web services before learning boot?

You should learn how spring works in general and how does instantiations work. Basically it does a search in your project and instantiate every class annotated with `@Component` (`@Service`, `@RestController`, `@Controller` ... and so on). When you `@Autowire`, a reference is passed to your variable.

> After getting confused by the multitude of websites doing things in completely different ways (completely different annotations, some use of configuration files) it worked and I then modified it using an interceptor/message converter, raw headers and then through a rest template builder.

Most of the examples that you can find on the internet older than 1-2 years are probably outdated(but not always). When you search for something keep this in mind. This is the main cause why there are so many implementations.

> I can find many resources on teaching me the various packages, but none that tells me why they work or where to really start and specifically nothing will tell me how the packages interlink. It's quite overwhelming.

It is overwhelming. It is a big framework with a large domain of applicability. Best place to learn how things work is: https://spring.io/docs/reference

Comment: Ok, thanks for taking the time out, but that (your link) is the big list I'm talking about. Where should I actually start in understanding all of this, any particular project as 'core' is not a package :) as I feel Spring boot got me up and running but really it taught me little. 

As you say lots of sites are out of date and Spring has changed from XML heavy to XML light, yet I cannot find much at the spring.io site that guides me on a journey of learning, i.e. fundamentals of Core (if there is such a thing).

Comment: Perhaps to avoid all this glut of out of date information a nice spring primer document could be made at the spring.io site that wasn't a specific isolated project reference guide and people would know it is relevant and current and stay at the site...?

Comment: That kind of document might be usefull for starters.
There is a `Spring Fundamentals` tutorial on pluralsight, kind of introduction. In my opinion you should ask yourself which module from Spring do you need (if you need any) and search how others implemented it in their project. If you want to build an app with Web Services you might choose one or multiple modules from Spring (web serv, data jpa, web security).