# BeanCreationException after fixing namespace issues

Tags: java, spring

This is a follow up question for [org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42941003/org-xml-sax-saxparseexceptioncvc-complex-type-2-4-c-the-matching-wildcard-is-s) The issue in that question is fixed but i'm now seeing BeanCreationException for stuff that was working before I made the change.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage com.xxx.service.EmployeeService.templateMessage; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

My REST controller is annotated this way

```
@RestController
public class EmployeeController
```

And my service

```
@Service("employeeService")
public class EmployeeService
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this/similar in your applicationContext xml file.

```
<bean id="simpleMailMessage"
    class="org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage">

    <property name="from" value="from@no-spam.com" />
    <property name="to" value="to@no-spam.com" />
    <property name="subject" value="Testing Subject" />
    <property name="text">
       <value>
        <![CDATA[
            Dear %s,
            Mail Content : %s
        ]]>
       </value>
        </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: I did this and I went back to my original problem of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42941003/org-xml-sax-saxparseexceptioncvc-complex-type-2-4-c-the-matching-wildcard-is-s

Comment: you can use javaconfig to get rid of xml issues like this.refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/24097225/1401019

Comment: Is that Javaconfig only applicable for Spring Boot? Also is there a full example I can follow?

Comment: It is not specific to Spring boot, you can refer this article for how-to of java config. https://samerabdelkafi.wordpress.com/2014/08/03/spring-mvc-full-java-based-config/

Comment: Refer official doc - http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/htmlsingle/spring-javaconfig-reference.html

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled the component scanning in Spring ?

Also below is an example of how your bean-configuration should be :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="customerService" class="com.abc.customer.services.CustomerService">
        <property name="customerDAO" ref="customerDAO" />
    </bean>
    enter code here
    <bean id="customerDAO" class="com.abc.customer.dao.CustomerDAO" />

</beans>
```